# Hide interface methods in spring data

Tags: java, spring-data, java-11

Is it possible to hide Spring Data custom methods?

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

    // this method should be hidden
    List<Entity> findByMyFieldName1AndByMyFieldName2AndByMyFieldName3(Long field1, Long field2, Long field3);

    default List<Entity> findRecord(Long field1, Long field2, Long field3) {
        return findByMyFieldName1AndByMyFieldName2AndByMyFieldName3(field1, field2, field3);
    }

}
```

I use Java 11

Comment: Hide it from who? Why not just remove the code?

Comment: are you trying to make it `private`? (you can since java-9)

Comment: @Naman if I make it private - Spring Data won't parse this method to query

Comment: If Spring Data doesn't parse it, who is going to implement it?